# How to delete a Cookie in Python

Tags: python, django, cookies

First of all, I've been searching and I couldn't find anything useful so I'm sorry if it is a very easy question, but I need help. I'm trying to delete a cookie with Python/Django, but I don't find the way.

I read the Cookie with this:

```
Cookie = request.COOKIES['item']
```

How could I delete this cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this in your view:

```
response.delete_cookie('cookie_name', domain="cookie_domain")
return response
```

Read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.delete_cookie) for details.